# Non-blocking batch file execution

Tags: batch-file

I have the following commands in a batch file:

```
"C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 19
"C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 20
"C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 21
"C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 23
"C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 25
```

I'm attempting to execute 5 instances of an application I created, passing in a different param to each. My goal is that when I run this batch file, it launches the 5 instances of this app, loading a UI component for each. Eventually I will make this more elegant, and put a wrapper app around this, but for now i just want these to run simultaneously.

The problem is, when I launch this batch file, it executes the first line, loading the UI. That's it. It doesn't move on to the second line. Thoughts?

Edit to Add - I could certainly do this from separate batch files, but I'd like to have one-click launching. 
Scott

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`start`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true):

```
start "" "C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 19
start "" "C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 20
start "" "C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 21
start "" "C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 23
start "" "C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" 25
```

The first argument is the title of the created command line window, which we don't care about, so it can be left empty.

Even better would be to use `for`:

```
forr %i in (19, 20, 21, 23, 25) do start "" "C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe" %i
```

Comment: The first set of quotation marks may be a bit confusing. They're for the title to display in the Windows title bar. If you include quotation marks for the path (eg. contains spaces), then the parser will need a title (which is blank is svick's answer). If your path does not need quotation marks, then you don't need to set the title. Type start /? at the command prompt for additional details.

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
start C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe 19
start C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe 20
```

etc.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me, it starts `cmd.exe` twice.

Comment: I removed the "" that might have confused it.

Comment: That's not the problem, at least on my computer.

Comment: There most be some issue, i tried it here (Windows 7) with exactly that syntax, and the application starts with the parameter. And `start /?` says that the syntax is start [command/program] [parameters]. The `""` would have been inteprerted as the title.

Answer (score 3):

Use start:

```
start C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe 19
start C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe 20
start C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe 21
start C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe 23
start C:\MI2\Stream\bin\Debug\Stream.exe 25
```

Comment: In what way? It's exactly the same solution as the others I just included the switch to stop it opening a new window.

Comment: When you enclose the path in `"`, it is treated at the window title, not that path to execute.

Comment: Ah I see, I tested it with ping (no quotes) as I didn't have a exe to hand. I'll revise.