# Can't kill program by taskkill

Tags: batch-file

I use Tecplot to opem its script file (*mcr) to do visulization. After I write the batch codes to first open tecplot to launch the *mcr file and then kill it, I found the codes can't terminate the program. The codes in batch file is as following:

```
cd .\Re100\17\
cd .\0.001
tec360 extract.mcr
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 100000 
taskkill /F /IM tec360.exe
cd ..\
cd .\0.005
extract.mcr
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 100000 
taskkill /F /IM tec360.exe
```

But, if I manually closed the Tecplot then the batch file can work. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your batch file stops and waits for Tecplot to exit before continuing.  You need to use the `start` command to launch it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295232/non-blocking-batch-file-execution.

Comment: Hi. I have tried to add a "start tec360.exe". But it still didn't work.

Comment: The link I pasted shows how to use the `start` command.  `start "" "tec360" extract.mcr`

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I have figured it out. Can you please explain the difference between "start" and "tec360" in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking on this site http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx It will show you how to use the task kill command.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a $!QUIT command in the end of your macro file "extract.mcr" that will close the tecplot after the macro has finished, this way your tecplot GUI will close itself. The macro file should look like this

```
#!MC 1410
# some other macro commands .....
$!QUIT
```

In my experience you don't really need the GUI of tecplot to load, you can run your macro in the batch mode which will be quick, and that won't require $!Quit command either. to run in batch mode your batch file look like this

```
cd .\Re100\17\0.001
tec360 -b extract.mcr
cd ..\0.005
tec360 -b extract.mcr
```

On an additional note, if you have same file name i.e. extract.mcr and a lot of folders where you want to run, then instead of hardcoding the bath like you did, in windows here is how it would be,

```
SET my_dir="Re100\17\0.001" "..\0.005"
FOR %%A IN (%my_dir%) DO (
    cd %%A
    tec360 -b extract.mcr
)
```

Now you can add as many folders in first line as you want with a space separating the paths for example
SET my_dir="path 1" "path_2" "path 3" "path 4"
and so on..

Comment: While adding *quit* to the .mcr looks the most direct solution, I have no information if not immediately quitting wasn't what was wanted a) when that file was created b) by Wei. Given the years gone by, we may never know.

Comment: That's true, but why would someone want to quit a program write after starting it, especially in a hard codded script !